# Atomiclong list in Hazelcast cluster

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Is there anyway in Hazelcast client to get the list of AtomicLongs present in the cluster. I might need to know the counter names to clear it, since there is no TTL for AtomicCounter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can list all distributed objects and filter AtomicLongs

```
        Collection<DistributedObject> distributedObjects = instance.getDistributedObjects();
        List<DistributedObject> atomicLongList = distributedObjects
            .stream()
            .filter(o -> o.getServiceName().equals(AtomicLongService.SERVICE_NAME))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.. Thank you