# Atomiclong list in Hazelcast cluster 4.0

Tags: hazelcast

Is there anyway in Hazelcast client to get the list of AtomicLongs present in the cluster. I might need to know the counter names to clear it, since there is no TTL for AtomicCounter. Earlier i used the approach mentioned here - [Atomiclong list in Hazelcast cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57629236/atomiclong-list-in-hazelcast-cluster)

But it no longer works in Hazelcast 4.X as IAtomicLong is part of CPSubsystem - https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.0/data-structures/iatomiclong

Answer (score 0):

There's an open issue in the backlog for this,
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/17135
so as of 5.1.1, the answer is "*no*"